# Why is degrees of freedom not considered while calculating standard deviations of samples in independent samples t-test?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, t-test, inference

In paired samples t-test, while calculating the standard deviation of differences, we take into consideration the degrees of freedom in the formula of calculating t by using n-1 instead of n for calculating stdev of sample.

Then why don't we use n-1 while calculating stddev for each of the independent samples in independent samples' t-test.

Comment: you should have the option to delete your own question.

Comment: The purpose of this website is to create a durable repository of statistics knowledge. For this reason, questions with upvoted and/or accepted answers are not generally eligible for deletion. You agreed to these terms when you signed up for the website. If you have questions about these terms or how the site works, you can ask a question on meta.SE.

Comment: I dispute the premise of the question

Answer (score 2):

In the case of paired observations you only fit one mean, in the case of independent samples you fit one mean for ech population.

Comment: Please refer to my question again. I am asking why don't we use n-1 while calculating stddev for each of the two samples in independent samples test.

Answer (score 1):

We do make use of degrees of freedom while calculating test-statistics for independent samples t-test. We make use of the pooled std.dev in the test statistic -
$S_p = \sqrt{\frac{(n_1-1)*(S_1)^2 + (n_2-1)*(S_2)^2}{n_1 + n_2 - 2}}$
where $S_1$ and $S_2$ are standard deviation of sample 1 and 2 respectively.

Comment: This pooled standard deviation is only used when the assumption is that the variance is equal. I am referring to generic version without assumption of equal variance.

Comment: Hi: if they aren't equal, there is no pivotal quantity and sattherwaite's approximation is often used. I don't know the derivation of that but it's an approximation so I wouldn't use that an example for how to calculate the degrees of freedom in a pivotal quantity.

Comment: @Atharva This answer responds to the question you appear to have asked in your posted question. If you meant to ask about what is often called Welch's test (i.e. using a Welch-Satterthwaite approximation) you should have specified that in your question. That isn't strictly a t-test (for reasons mlofton pointed out), it instead uses a t-approximation to the distribution of the statistic. The variance estimate in the Welch test *does* make use of the n-1 divisor in computing both $s_1$ and $s_2$, and uses the individual-sample degrees of freedom again ... ctd

Comment: ctd...  when computing the d.f. for the t-approximation to the null distribution.